# Signal encoding on Realtek TX2 IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, signal, modulation, encoder, demodulation

I 'm trying to figure out the way IC [TX2](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FWW/CD13/GV525G0X/FWWCD13GV525G0X.pdf) encodes different signals (RIGHT, LEFT, FORWARD, BACKWARD, TURBO).

I can understand that presence of voltage means an appropriate signal to be transmitted. "SO" is the output pin of the encoded signal (digital pulses). Thereafter, encoded signal will be modulated onto a carrier, in order to be transmitted. Question is, how input signals (e.g. RIGHT, LEFT) are differenciated on the IC?

Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have some test equipment, e.g., an oscilloscope, I'd first look for [Pulse Position Modulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-position_modulation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Realtek's Datasheet:

[image]

Notice that the Datasheet that question provides, is from Actions Semiconductor Co., Ltd.